# Magento 2 fresh install on Debian 10 with nginx not working

Tags: magento2

[image]

How can I fix this? I followed Magento's docs for installing.

I'm using php7.4 and MySQL 8.

Answer (score 0):

This One Worked for Me. Use this Command PHP bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Step 1: In CMD Open your root directory using the cd command

Step 2: run this Command

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

then, check your pub/static folder, CSS and Js files will be available there

Or you should adjust the filesystem permissions and maybe the webserver rewrites: https://mage2.pro/t/259